# Three.js + Fabric.js raycast works with mouse but not touch events on mobile device

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fabricjs, threejs-editor

I've been trying to solve the problem for several days, but so far all in vain. I am hope for your help.

Based on https://codepen.io/naonvl/pen/ExbjejL

Code below:

```
/**
* Fabric.js patch
*/
fabric.Canvas.prototype.getPointer =  function (e, ignoreZoom) {
  if (this._absolutePointer && !ignoreZoom) {
    return this._absolutePointer;
  }
  if (this._pointer && ignoreZoom) {
    return this._pointer;
  }
var simEvt;
        if (e.touches != undefined) {
            simEvt = new MouseEvent({
                touchstart: "mousedown",
                touchmove: "mousemove",
                touchend: "mouseup"
            }[e.type], {
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true,
                view: window,
                detail: 1,
                screenX: Math.round(e.changedTouches[0].screenX),
                screenY: Math.round(e.changedTouches[0].screenY),
                clientX: Math.round(e.changedTouches[0].clientX),
                clientY: Math.round(e.changedTouches[0].clientY),
                ctrlKey: false,
                altKey: false,
                shiftKey: false,
                metaKey: false,
                button: 0,
                relatedTarget: null
            });
            var pointer = fabric.util.getPointer(simEvt),
                upperCanvasEl = this.upperCanvasEl,
                bounds = upperCanvasEl.getBoundingClientRect(),
                boundsWidth = bounds.width || 0,
                boundsHeight = bounds.height || 0,
                cssScale;
        } else {
            var pointer = fabric.util.getPointer(e),
                upperCanvasEl = this.upperCanvasEl,
                bounds = upperCanvasEl.getBoundingClientRect(),
                boundsWidth = bounds.width || 0,
                boundsHeight = bounds.height || 0,
                cssScale;
        }
  if (!boundsWidth || !boundsHeight ) {
    if ('top' in bounds && 'bottom' in bounds) {
      boundsHeight = Math.abs( bounds.top - bounds.bottom );
    }
    if ('right' in bounds && 'left' in bounds) {
      boundsWidth = Math.abs( bounds.right - bounds.left );
    }
  }
  this.calcOffset();
  pointer.x = pointer.x - this._offset.left;
  pointer.y = pointer.y - this._offset.top;
  /* BEGIN PATCH CODE */
 if (e.target !== this.upperCanvasEl) {
            var positionOnScene;
            if (isMobile == true) {
                positionOnScene = getPositionOnSceneTouch(container, e);
                if (positionOnScene) {
                    console.log(positionOnScene);
                    pointer.x = positionOnScene.x;
                    pointer.y = positionOnScene.y;
                }
            } else {
                positionOnScene = getPositionOnScene(container, e);
                if (positionOnScene) {
                    console.log(positionOnScene);
                    pointer.x = positionOnScene.x;
                    pointer.y = positionOnScene.y;
                }
            }
        }
  /* END PATCH CODE */
  if (!ignoreZoom) {
    pointer = this.restorePointerVpt(pointer);
  }

  if (boundsWidth === 0 || boundsHeight === 0) {
    cssScale = { width: 1, height: 1 };
  }
  else {
    cssScale = {
      width: upperCanvasEl.width / boundsWidth,
      height: upperCanvasEl.height / boundsHeight
    };
  }

  return {
    x: pointer.x * cssScale.width,
    y: pointer.y * cssScale.height
  };
}
  
  /**
   * Listeners
   */
  
  container.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseEvt, false);
  
if (
    /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(
        navigator.userAgent,
    ) ||
    /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(
        navigator.userAgent.substr(0, 4),
    )
) {
    isMobile = true;
    container.addEventListener("touchstart", onTouch, false);
}
  /**
   * Event handler
   */
  
function onTouch(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const positionOnScene = getPositionOnSceneTouch(container, evt);
    if (positionOnScene) {
        const canvasRect = canvas._offset;
        const simEvt = new MouseEvent(evt.type, {
            clientX: canvasRect.left + positionOnScene.x,
            clientY: canvasRect.top + positionOnScene.y,
        });
        canvas.upperCanvasEl.dispatchEvent(simEvt);
    }
}

function getPositionOnSceneTouch(sceneContainer, evt) {
    var array = getMousePosition(sceneContainer, evt.changedTouches[0].clientX, evt.changedTouches[0].clientY);
    onClickPosition.fromArray(array);
  console.log(scene);
    var intersects = getIntersects(onClickPosition, scene.children);
    if (intersects.length > 0 && intersects[0].uv) {
        var uv = intersects[0].uv;
        intersects[0].object.material.map.transformUv(uv);
        var circle = new fabric.Circle({
            radius: 3,
            left: getRealPosition("x", uv.x),
            top: getRealPosition("y", uv.y),
            fill: "white",
        });
        // canvas.add(circle);
        getUv = uv;
        return {
            x: getRealPosition("x", uv.x),
            y: getRealPosition("y", uv.y),
        };
    }
    return null;
}
  function onMouseEvt(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const positionOnScene = getPositionOnScene(container, evt)
    if (positionOnScene) {
      const canvasRect = canvas._offset;
      const simEvt = new MouseEvent(evt.type, {
        clientX: canvasRect.left + positionOnScene.x,
        clientY: canvasRect.top + positionOnScene.y
      });

      console.log(simEvt);

      canvas.upperCanvasEl.dispatchEvent(simEvt);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Three.js Helper functions
   */
  function getPositionOnScene(sceneContainer, evt) {
  console.log(evt);
  console.log(scene);
    var array = getMousePosition(container, evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
    onClickPosition.fromArray(array);
    var intersects = getIntersects(onClickPosition, scene.children);
    if (intersects.length > 0 && intersects[0].uv) {
      var uv = intersects[0].uv;
      intersects[0].object.material.map.transformUv(uv);
      return {
        x: getRealPosition('x', uv.x),
        y: getRealPosition('y', uv.y)
      }
    }
    return null
  }
  
  function getRealPosition(axis, value) {
    let CORRECTION_VALUE = axis === "x" ? 4.5 : 5.5;
  
    return Math.round(value * 512) - CORRECTION_VALUE;
  }
  
  var getMousePosition = function(dom, x, y) {
    var rect = dom.getBoundingClientRect();
    return [(x - rect.left) / rect.width, (y - rect.top) / rect.height];
  };
  
  var getIntersects = function(point, objects) {
    mouse.set(point.x * 2 - 1, -(point.y * 2) + 1);
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    return raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
  };
```

The code works on desktop but doesn't work on mobile device. I'm trying to move a fabricjs canvas directly over a threejs model and move/scale the canvas from a 3d model. This works great on PC but not on mobile.
Touch events for some reason do not seem to be recognized.

On the PC, the object can be selected and modified, but on mobile - only select the object, but not move around the model.